# Claims Identity in SignalR 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to get claims-based authorization from ASP.NET MVC5 working with SignalR, and I've followed this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization

I tried both the vanilla `Authorize` attribute on the hub as well as the custom `AuthorizeClaimsAttribute` class they give as an example, but neither of them seem to work.

In the latter case, the `IPrincipal user` parameter is coming in as null. In fact, the entire context returned by the `request.GetOwinContext()` extension method appears to be uninitialized, so trying to dig through the object to get it "for free" won't work.

I did, however, see these cookies in the request header:

- .AspNet.ApplicationCookie
- __RequestVerificationToken
- ASP.NET_SessionId

All of them contained instances of `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie`.

Is the only way to get this working to do my own cookie parsing/decryption? If so, how?

Comment: Did you modified web.config so that your auth class catches the event?

Comment: No, can you explain?

Answer (score 5):

It turns out the issue is to do with the order of handler registration in the `Startup` class.

I was calling `app.MapSignalR()` before calling `app.UseCookieAuthentication(...)`, but simply by switching the order everything started working.

What's more, it works with the normal `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute` applied to the hub directly, no need for a custom attribute.

Comment: You are brilliant! I had the same problem and the cause of the issue isn't obvious, so thank you!